# The CSS ::before pseudo element doesn't seem to be working. I can't seem to find out as to why nor get a solution online

Tags: html, css

**Objective:** Insert '/' before each list item after the first list item.
**Current Outcome:** '/' not visible/not displayed/won't show.

*I have attached my CSS and HTML codes below*

```css
.breadcrumbs  {
  object-fit: contain;
  padding-left: 0.3em;

}

.breadcrumbs li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 0.3em;

}

.breadcrumbs li+li::before {
  content: "/\00a0";
}

.breadcrumbs li a {
  color: var(--nav_color);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: large;
}

.breadcrumbs li a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: powderblue;
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
      <li><a href="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML_CSS_JS_practice\Chairmaster\Codes\home_landing.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML_CSS_JS_practice\Chairmaster\Codes\products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML_CSS_JS_practice\Chairmaster\Codes\contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML_CSS_JS_practice\Chairmaster\Codes\reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in the code snippet

Comment: @YongQuan When i try it in the browser(chrome Version 74.0.3729.169), it doesn't.

Comment: I just tried on Mac, in Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just write the forward slash as a '/'.

Set the width of the box to be the size of the space, center aligning the text.

```
{
    content: '/';
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT:** how I would have written it...

```css
 .breadcrumbs  {
  object-fit: contain;
  padding: 10px;
 }

 .breadcrumbs li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
    /* if you remove the line breaks in the html between your li's you can use display: inline-block; and remove the float left */
 }

 .breadcrumbs li+li:before {
  content: '/';
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 .breadcrumbs li a {
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 .breadcrumbs li a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: powderblue;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
 <li><a href="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML_CSS_JS_practice\Chairmaster\Codes\home_landing.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML_CSS_JS_practice\Chairmaster\Codes\products.html">Products</a></li>
 <li><a href="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML_CSS_JS_practice\Chairmaster\Codes\contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="D:\ghanesh\ghanesh\Y Combinator\Intern Summer 2019\interning Prep Course\HTML_CSS_JS_practice\Chairmaster\Codes\reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
</ul>
```

Ta, J

Comment: remove one of your ':' in your ::before declaration. So try :before. It may be a compatibility issue.

Comment: Ive written out how I would have wrote it initially before testing it. Can you try that?

Comment: i tried incorporating your code into my mine. Seems like using `display: inline-block;` and `content: '/' ;` did the trick.